# Hyperledger Fabric CA High availability

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'd like to configure 2 CAs/Org for HA and I refer to Fabric CA Server document.

I have two questions,

1. How to setup multiple CAs in two servers? 
   In the document, there is an instruction of Setting up multiple CAs but it is single server configuration.
2. The following is my understanding of Fabric CA HA. Is it correct?

   - Configure multiple Fabric-CA
   - Postgres or MySQL database configuration is required.
     In order to avoid SPOF, the database must be HA.
   - HAProxy is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

In order to set up an HA pair of fabric-ca servers, you need to use either PostgreSQL or MySQL as the database.  You'll then configure each fabric-ca server instance to use the same database.

In order to prevent the database from being a single point of failure, you'll need to set up your database in a fault tolerant / high availability configuration as well.

And finally, if you simply want to distribute requests across both fabric-ca servers, you can leverage something like HAProxy for load balancing.